# Enum practices - Define inside a class/separately, make public/private

Tags: java, enums

What is a good practise when defining an enum?

For example, I have a Person class. For this class I have chosen to use an enum which has the values MALE and FEMALE.

Should the enum be defined inside the Person class or separately? Should the enum be defined as private or public? Also, do you have any further advice that would make using an enum as flexible as possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IMHO, make it a `public static enum` inside `class Person`.

The reason is the `enum Gender` applies only to Person, so put it in there so they're bound together (Gender has no use without the context of a Person).

The upside:

- less class bloat
- if you move Person to another package/project, Gender will always come with it
- Person, who is the only user, has "control" of it and may alter it as it wants, eg

  - adding `private List<HealthIssue> genderSpecificHealthIssues;`
  - adding more enums, eg `TRANSGENDER`, `INTERSEX`, or whatever

The only downside is you must use a `static` import to use it, ie `import static com.company.Person.Gender.*;`.

This pattern is seen in many JDK classes, such as `Calendar` which defines the many date-related constants it uses *inside* the class.

Answer (score 3):

For full flexibility, add it to a static class. But of course this is only and solely for enums that need to be used throughout the entire application. For local and specialized enums, it's better to keep them 'close' to where they'll be used. *Exampli gratia*, I have an IPHandler class that makes the handling, parsing and translating IPv4 and IPv6 addresses transparent for the class user (IPHandler is a static class). It has one enum, IPType, with values IPv4 and IPv6 that are only used within IPHandler for several operations. Since it's not used anywhere else, it's been defined within the IPHandler class.

Comment: @leon: Thank you for sharing. Just to confirm, IPType is not used in setters/getters and is defined as private?

Comment: @James P. - since the method calls of IPHandler use the enum (as in _IPHandler.getFormattedLocal(**IPHandler.IPType ipType**))_, they must be accessible from outside its parent class. This means no, they can't be private - and should not have setters. Does Java allow that?

Comment: Ok, I get you. When I mentionned getters and setters I meant those of your IPHandler class. It's necessary to have the enum set as publicly accessible if they're referenced in methods. This leaves me wondering in what cases it would be a good idea to define an enum as a separate Java file. P.S: Just for the detail, enums can have variable/methods added although these obviously can't modify the actual enum values.

Comment: @leon: It appears you have you good general culture when it comes to programming languages then :)